# Можно ли передать строку в переменную больше длины char?

Tags: c, char, типы-данных

Написал простую функцию для будущей программы, которая записывает сообщения в файл (обычное логирование).

```
bool mess(char *mess)
{
    char *ptr=(char*)calloc(1,strlen(mess)+31);

    const time_t t=time(NULL);
    strftime(ptr,30,"%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S|  ",localtime(&t));
    strcat(ptr,mess);

    FILE *fd=fopen("/var/log/info.log","at");
    if (fd == NULL) 
    {
        return false;
    }
    fprintf(fd,"%s\n",ptr);
    fclose(fd);

    free(ptr);

    return true;
}
```

Сразу не пишу в файл, т.к. между strftime и strcat буду еще подготавливать строку. Функцию буду вызывать в программе так

```
mess("какая-то неопределенная строка").
```

Как я разобрался char это 8 байт, а строка может быть передана большей длины.
Если добавить такую проверку в начале функции

```
printf("%i",strlen(mess));
printf("%i",sizeof(mess));
```

То выведет 31 и 8. Нужно ли использовать другой тип для для переменной mess? Будут ли какие-то последствия для памяти, что строка передалась более 8 байт? Это важно, т.к. будущая программа будет крутиться сутками на сервере.

Comment: Вы разобрались неправильно. char* - это указатель на память. Он может показывать на участок памяти огромных размеров.

Comment: У вас огромная проблема с производительностью - переоткрытие файла на каждый чих.

Comment: Каждый чих будет раз в час) А насчет char спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Велосипед для ведения логов нежелателен. Есть `syslog`. Он умеет сам фиксировать время, формировать красивые журналы, передавать их на другие сервера и использовать технологии их автоматического анализа. А также с ним проще настроить рассылку уведомлений в случае проблем.
2. Если вы все же хотите написать велосипед (многим так комфортнее, но комфортнее - это не всегда правильно) - вы это сделали. Ваш код верен и будет вполне неплохо работать.
3. Переоткрытие файла даст вам проблемы с производительностью.
4. Использование `calloc` здесь не уместно, нет смысла в инициализации. Замените на `malloc`.

Comment: Велосипед и переоткрытие файла нужны по разным причинам, но они не относятся к вопросу)
При malloc нужно в конце строки добавлять 0, т.е. лишняя операция. При использовании calloc её использовать не надо.
Меня именно мучает вопрос по большей величины строки, если она char. Как это скажется на память?

Comment: @nerik - strcat и strftime сами ставят ноль куда надо. Это про я про calloc. Я уже два раза вам сказал, что char* - указатель, и он показывает не на 8 байт (откуда вы взяли 8 байт?), а сколько угодно программисту.

Comment: @neric, при вызове calloc выделенная память обнуляется не магическим образом, а буквально записью нулей в каждую выделенную ячейку. А это уже не одна лишняя операция, а N, где N кратно длине строки.

Comment: @gbg действительно ставят) спасибо, тут буду теперь знать.